# How can I get attribute form an element in the variable?

Tags: jquery, attributes

For example, I have

```
var element = "<input type=\"number\" id=\"anElement\">"
```

I want to retrieve the id

I am trying this code :

```
var newvalueFonts = element.attr('id').val();
```

and it is not working. Why?

***Am I doing it worng or I just have to fix code little bit***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put that string in a jQuery object, then call `prop()` on it to get the `id`:

```js
var element = '<input type="number" id="anElement">';
var newvalueFonts = $(element).prop('id');

console.log(newvalueFonts);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For your reference your original code (`var newvalueFonts = element.attr('id').val();`) doesn't work as `element` is a string, so there is no `attr()` method on it. Even if it was, `attr()` itself returns a string which also has no `val()` method.

Answer (score 2):

After doing var element = "" you need to attach the element into the DOM  using $("#divid").append(element) (divid is the id into which we need to put the input element). After that you can use

var newvalueFonts = $("input[type=number]").attr('id');

Answer (score 1):

You can create a jQuery object using the string, then use various methods on it.

```
var newvalueFonts = $(element).attr('id');
```

```js
var element = "<input type=\"number\" id=\"anElement\">";
var newvalueFonts = $(element).attr('id');
console.log(newvalueFonts)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var element = "<input type=\"number\" id=\"anElement\">"


var newvalueFonts = $(element).attr('id')
console.log(newvalueFonts)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

1. Wrap in `$()`
2. No need for `.val()` to get `.attr()`